# Conditional operator using a int value

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

I came across a statement that has left my head confused.

Assume x >= 0

```
(x - 1 ? 16:11)
```

Apparently this code has the same response as

```
(x > 1 ? 16:11)
```

Can someone explain how the minus one works? I thought that conditional operators had to provide a true or false result. I don't understand how an integer can fit into a conditional operator.

Comment: You can put anything into a conditional, it will then be coerced to an boolean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the code:

```
(x - 1 ? 16 : 11)
```

if `x` is equal to `1`, `x - 1` is `0` and `0` is falsy so the expression evaluates to `11`. Otherwise, `x - 1` is truthy and the expression evaluates to `16`.

Comment: I was just about to write the same thing

Comment: And also for more information about what **falsy** is, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

Comment: Why would developers prefer to write this instead of a equality operator? Wouldn't the equality operator be 'safer'?

Answer (score 2):

The conditional operator is evaluating the result of your expression.

Assuming `x = 2` the results would be:

`2 - 1 = 1`
`2 > 1 = true`

Assuming `x = 1` the results would be:

`1 - 1 = 0`
`1 > 1 = false`

`0` will be treated as `false`. `1` as `true`.

So both expressions will have the same result.

**But be aware:**
If you do use negative numbers the expressions will have different results, since negative numbers will be treated as `true` by the conditional operator.

`-3 - 1 = -4 => true`

`-3 > 1 = false`

Comment: nitpick: it is the "conditional operator", which is just one of the possible ternary operators (meaning: 3 operands). Not that I know of any others, however ...

Comment: Thanks! I changed my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could use some values to get an idea what is going on.

```
 x - 1 ? 16 : 11

-1 - 1              -2 truthy -> 16
 0 - 1              -1 truthy -> 16
 1 - 1               0 falsy  -> 11
 2 - 1               1 truthy -> 16
 3 - 1               2 truthy -> 16
```

Based on this, the condition could be rewritten to

```
 x !== 1 ? 16 : 11
```

Answer (score 1):

values greater than `0` or less than `0` are taken as `true` in conditional statements, and zero is taken as `false`

```
(1)?"true": "false";
(0)?"true": "false";
```

```js
console.log((-1)? "true": "false");
console.log((1)? "true": "false");
console.log((0)? "true": "false");
```